# Remove specified index from multi level array of php

Tags: php

i am using multi level array, arrays inside an array. and i have an index "|" and i am using this for only cloning of form elements, but when i save form, it become part of my php arrays. please let me know how can i remove it with short code.I also used PHP functions "array_walk" and "array_walk_recursive" but no success, following is display of my array of arrays

```
Array
(
[banner_heading] => Get Started Here!
[banner_text] => <pre id="line1">aaaa</pre>
[banner_button] => [button_blue link="#"]Buy Now[/button_blue]
[banner_media] => image
[upload_banner] => /wp-content/uploads/2013/07/videoImg.jpg
[youtube_video] => Oo3f1MaYyD8
[vimeo_video] => 24456787
[intro_heading] => Anyone Can Accept Credit Cards with Square
[intro_text] => 
[feature_content] => Array
    (
        [1] => Array
            (
                [title] => Free Secure Card Reader
                [description] => Sign up and we’ll mail you a free card reader. The reader fits right in your pocket and securely encrypts every swipe.
                [link] => #
                [icon] => /wp-content/uploads/2013/07/cardIcon.jpg
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [title] => Easy Setup
                [description] => Download the free Square Register app and link your bank account. No setup fees or long-term contracts. You’ll be accepting payments on your smartphone or iPad in minutes.
                [link] => #
                [icon] => /wp-content/uploads/2013/07/easyIcon.jpg
            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [title] => Simple Pricing
                [description] => Pay just 2.75% per swipe for all major credit cards or a flat monthly $275. No other fees—so you know exactly what you pay. Square’s pricing fits businesses of all sizes.
                [link] => #
                [icon] => /wp-content/uploads/2013/07/pricingIcon.jpg
            )

        [5] => Array
            (
                [title] => 
                [description] => 
                [link] => 
                [icon] => 
            )

        [|] => Array
            (
                [title] => 
                [description] => 
                [link] => 
                [icon] => 
            )

    )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [unset](https://www.php.net/unset):

```
$array; // this is your array

unset($array['feature_content']['|']);
```

Comment: i can not do that because i have to do some dynamic code, i write a function to clean my all array, but is doing nothing.

Comment: function _CL( $Arr ){
 if( is_array( $Arr ) ){
  unset( $Arr['|'] );
  foreach( $Arr as $input_ind => $input_val ){
   if( is_array( $input_val ) ){
    unset( $input_val['|'] );
    _CL( $input_val ); 
   }
  }
 }
 return $Arr;
}

Answer (score 0):

The following function can be used to recursively get the path in your array to the nodes whose keys are `|`. It returns an array of path nodes concatenated in a string separated colons such as `$out = array('key1:key2:|', 'key3:|');`:

```
function get_path($arr, $path = array()) {
    $out = array();
    foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
        $full = array_merge($path, array($key));
        if ($key === '|') {
            $out[] = join(':', $full);
        } elseif (is_array($value)) {
            $out = array_merge($out, get_path($value, $full));
        }
    }
    return $out;
}
```

Once you get that, you can clean your array as follows:

```
$out = $this->get_path($arr);
if ( ! empty($out)){
    foreach ($out as $str){
        $path = explode(':', $str);
        array_pop($path);
        $nester = &$arr;
        foreach ($path as $node){
            $nester = &$nester[$node];
        }
        unset($nester['|']);
    }
}
print_r($arr);
```